# Connection between thermodynamic potentials stability criteria and Gibbs potential minima in phase transition

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

As I was studying chapters 8 and 9 of Callen's books, I wondered about the following missing link.
In Chapter 8, a function of entropy S with respect to an extensive variable is shown:
[image]

It is argued that such a function would not yield a stable thermodynamic configuration in the middle region, for instance in point D.
Then Callen provide a rule to obtain the stable state, by constructing tangent lines that lie above the curve, without really explaining the reason behind such construction.

Now, turning to chapter 9, it gives a really nice explanation about transition phases based on considering a local volume in a gas, the fact that its Gibbs potential has the following function to the volume. The small volume can choose to be either in a gas state in one minimum, or in the liquid phase in the other minimum. These minimum change height based on the temperature, and this cause the liquid-gas transition.

[image]

Now, my question is: how the construction of the entropy and the stability criteria, which is extended also to the Gibbs potential, is connected to the presence of these two minima?
How the BHF segment should represent for instance the choice of one minimum over the other?
Is it based on the fact that in the entropy representation, following S(V) would require to consider thermodynamic states with both liquid and gas, and thus that average entropy over a proportion of the two states?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with your first question on entropy. The construction is used to explain phase coexistence. Take for example the liquid gas transition and that the $X$ is the total volume. The curve represents the entropy $S(V)$ of a homogenous fluid at volume $V$. The main assumption is the additivity of entropy and volume. If your system has a coexistence of two phases, of respective fraction $x_1,x_2$ ($x_1,x_2>0$ and $x_1+x_2=1$), volume $V_1,V_2$, and entropy $S_1=S(V_1),S_2=S(V_2),$ then:
$$
V = x_1V_1+x_2V_2 \\
S = x_1S_1+x_2v_2
$$
This is the mathematical translation of your last question. In real life, this may not be the case due to interfaces. Now, to determine the equilibrium state, you need to maximise $S$ (assuming that your system is isolated, if instead it is maintained at constant temperature). Out of all the candidate states, you need to include homogeneous states and coexisting phases as well. The graphical construction shows that at the volume corresponding to $H,$ you can achieve a higher entropy compared to a homogeneous phase by making a coexistence of volume corresponding to $B$ and corresponding to $F$. The respective fractions $x_B,x_F$ are obtained by solving the system since you know $V,V_B,V_F,S,S_B,S_F$. You therefore obtain a first order transition.

Mathematically, the entropy of the optimal phase coexistence is obtained by the convex hull of the hypograph of the homogeneous entropy graph. This amounts to doing the tangent line construction. Another way of seeing it is to use:
$$
P = -\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}
$$
so the two states $B,F$ have the same pressure and can coexist.

I'm not sure about the second approach though. It makes little sense to graph $G$, the free enthalpy as a function of $V$, it would be more appropriate to graph $F$, the free energy as a function of $V$. In this case, the same reasoning as for entropy applies since at constant temperature, you need to minimise $F$. You can use the common tangent construction to find the phase coexistence and the relative fractions.

If you really want to use $G$, then you need to look at $G$ as a function of $P$. You'll typically get a swallow tail, and the slopes of discontinuity gives you the volumes of the respective phases (the analogue of the $V_B,V_F$ in the previous example). You can check out Schroeder's *Thermal Physics* section 5.3 for more details (you'll also see another equivalent approach, the Maxwell construction).

Hope this helps.